# How do I modify create_report function of DataExplorer package?

Tags: r

I'm doing Exploratory Data analysis of my data using create_report function of package dataExplorer. I have some factor attributes. I want to customize my create_report function, so that if any factor has less than or equal to `n` levels it will display all the levels inside data structure portion which it generates using plot_str function & if level is more than n then it will show only variable name followed by number of levels. Can you suggest me how to do that?
The sample code I used is

```
create_report(iris)
```

Here species contains 3 level,setosa-versicolor-virginica, so in outcome it's showing `species (Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",)`. So if my n is 3 or above then it will show all the three levels like this `species (Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor","virginica")` other wise it will only show `species (Factor w/ 3 levels)`. Can you guide me?

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Why not just creating another variable? `customize_factor <- function(x, n) {l <- length(levels(x)); if (l > n) paste0("Factor w/ ", l, " levels")}`. Then compare the output of `iris$f1 <- customize_factor(iris$Species, 3)` and `iris$f2 <- customize_factor(iris$Species, 4)` to see if this is what you want.